# PHP Google OAuth - Missing Method?

Tags: php, oauth

I'm currently working on something using the Buzz API, and I've installed the Google Api PHP Client library.

When I run it, it goes all very well, until I get an error message saying that:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method apiClient::getAccessToken() in (URL) on line 42
```

I have made Notepad++ search within ALL the files for this method, but there is not a single declaration of it.  Please could someone provide the source code for this method or tell me where I could acquire it?

Comment: the problem is that you use it somewhere and it is not declared.. so search after getAccessToken() and see where it is used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which parameters is this function called with?

I found this one for you: [gData Sample](http://www.google.com/codesearch#E8kJFkn8iIU/trunk/hybrid/index.php&q=getAccessToken%20package%3ahttp://gdata-samples%5C.googlecode%5C.com&l=193)

I repacked it for easier external use: [smarcombes/HybridAuth](https://github.com/smarcombes/HybridAuth/blob/master/hybridauth/Hybrid/thirdparty/Google/hybrid-authdance-essentials.php#L40)